# Change order of for loops?

Tags: java, loops, dynamic, 3d, coords

I have a situation where i need to loop though xyz coordinates in different orders depending on a users input. So i an area in 3D space then a set of for loops like so.

```
for(int x = 0; x < build.getWidth(); x++){
   for(int y = 0; y < build.getHeight(); y++){
     for(int z = 0; z < build.getLength(); z++){
        //do stuff
       }
    }
 }
```

but depending on the users input, the order may be like this.

```
for(int z = 0; z < build.getLenght(); z++){
   for(int y = 0; y < build.getHeight(); y++){
     for(int x = 0; x < build.getWidth(); x++){
        //do stuff
       }
    }
 }
```

or even negative.

```
for(int x = build.getWidth(); x > 0; x--){
   for(int y = 0; y < build.getHeight(); y++){
      for(int z = 0; z < build.getLength(); z++){
        //do stuff
      }
   }
}
```

Is there any way to do this without hard coding every case?

Comment: Use iterators instead. Your program is hardcoded to iterate over them as `iter1`, `iter2`, `iter3`, but before entering the loops, set them up according to user input.

Comment: That could work. I would just need to setup some collections for the  xyz coords and reverse them if i need to in the opposite direction.

Comment: @aioobe if this was an answer I would have up voted it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an n-dimensional stepper that can step in any number of dimensions in any order from any start locations to any limits. See the test code for an example.

```
public class Test {
  public void test() {
    int[] limits = {3, -5, 7};
    int[] order = {0, 2, 1};
    int[] starts = {0, 0, 0};
    int[] steps = {1, -1, 2};
    NDimensionalStepper nds = new NDimensionalStepper(limits, order, starts, steps);
    do {
      System.out.println(nds);
    } while (nds.step());
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    new Test().test();
  }

  public static class NDimensionalStepper {
    // The current positions in each dimension.
    // Note that i[order[0]] is the fastest mover.
    final int[] i;
    // Starts.
    final int[] starts;
    // Steps.
    final int[] steps;
    // Limits.
    final int[] limits;
    // Order.
    final int[] order;
    // The (unordered) dimension we last stepped.
    int d = 0;

    // Full constructor.
    public NDimensionalStepper(int[] limits, int[] order, int[] starts, int[] steps) {
      // Should parameter check to ensure all are the same length.
      // Should also check that each dimension will terminate.
      this.i = Arrays.copyOf(starts, starts.length);
      this.starts = Arrays.copyOf(starts, starts.length);
      this.steps = Arrays.copyOf(steps, steps.length);
      this.limits = Arrays.copyOf(limits, limits.length);
      this.order = Arrays.copyOf(order, order.length);
    }

    // Default steps to 1.
    public NDimensionalStepper(int[] limits, int[] order, int[] starts) {
      this(limits, order, starts, defaultSteps(limits, starts));
    }

    // Default steps - 1 Towards limits.
    private static int[] defaultSteps(int[] limits, int[] starts) {
      int[] steps = new int[limits.length];
      for (int i = 0; i < limits.length; i++) {
        // Step towrds limits.
        steps[i] = (int) Math.signum(limits[i] - starts[i]);
      }
      return steps;
    }

    // Default starts to 0.
    public NDimensionalStepper(int[] limits, int[] order) {
      this(limits, order, defaultStarts(limits.length));
    }

    // Default starts - 0, 0, ...
    private static int[] defaultStarts(int d) {
      int[] starts = new int[d];
      Arrays.fill(starts, 0);
      return starts;
    }

    // Default order to normal.
    public NDimensionalStepper(int[] limits) {
      this(limits, defaultOrder(limits.length));
    }

    // Default order - ..., 1, 0
    private static int[] defaultOrder(int d) {
      int[] order = new int[d];
      for (int i = 0; i < d; i++) {
        order[i] = d - i - 1;
      }
      return order;
    }

    // Get the current position in dimension d.
    public int get(int d) {
      return i[d];
    }

    // Take just one step. Return false if cant.
    public boolean step() {
      boolean stepped = false;
      boolean finished = false;
      while (!stepped && !finished) {
        // Which dimension should be stepped (depends on order).
        int o = order[d];
        // Can we step in the current dimension?
        while (finished(o) && d < order.length - 1) {
          // Reached a limit! - Move up one dimension.
          o = order[++d];
        }
        if (d < order.length && !finished(o)) {
          // Step it.
          i[o] += steps[o];
          stepped = true;
          // Zero all lower dimensions.
          while (d > 0) {
            d -= 1;
            i[order[d]] = starts[order[d]];
          }
        } else {
          // Got to the last without finding one below limit. Finished!
          finished = true;
        }
      }
      return !finished;
    }

    // Equal or passed the limits.
    private boolean finished(int o) {
      int sign = (int) Math.signum(steps[o]);
      return sign * (i[o] + steps[o]) >= sign * limits[o];
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
      s.append("{");
      for (int d = 0; d < order.length; d++) {
        s.append(get(d));
        if (d < order.length - 1) {
          s.append(",");
        }
      }
      s.append("}");
      return s.toString();
    }
  }
}
```

My tests of the equivalents of your three scenarios look like:

```
  private void testBuild1(Build build) {
    System.out.println("Build: x,y,z");
    for (int x = 0; x < build.getWidth(); x++) {
      for (int y = 0; y < build.getHeight(); y++) {
        for (int z = 0; z < build.getLength(); z++) {
          System.out.println("{" + x + "," + y + "," + z + "}");
        }
      }
    }
    int[] limits = {build.getWidth(), build.getHeight(), build.getLength()};
    testNDS(new NDimensionalStepper(limits));
  }

  private void testBuild2(Build build) {
     System.out.println("Build: z,y,x");
    for (int z = 0; z < build.getLength(); z++) {
      for (int y = 0; y < build.getHeight(); y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < build.getWidth(); x++) {
          System.out.println("{" + x + "," + y + "," + z + "}");
        }
      }
    }
    int[] limits = {build.getWidth(), build.getHeight(), build.getLength()};
    int[] order = {0,1,2};
    testNDS(new NDimensionalStepper(limits, order));
  }

  private void testBuild3(Build build) {
    System.out.println("Build: x--,y,z");
    for (int x = build.getWidth(); x > 0; x--) {
      for (int y = 0; y < build.getHeight(); y++) {
        for (int z = 0; z < build.getLength(); z++) {
          System.out.println("{" + x + "," + y + "," + z + "}");
        }
      }
    }
    int[] limits = {0, build.getHeight(), build.getLength()};
    int[] order = {2,1,0};
    int[] starts = {build.getWidth(), 0, 0};
    int[] steps = {-1, 1, 1};
    testNDS(new NDimensionalStepper(limits, order, starts, steps));
  }

  private void testNDS(NDimensionalStepper nds) {
    System.out.println("--nds--");
    do {
      System.out.println(nds);
    } while (nds.step());
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You said depending on user input the order of loop changes. The logic for handling user input will have to be written.

You can code like this:

```
//Code to populate XInit, XEnd, YInit, YEnd, ZInit, ZEnd based on user input

    for(int x = XInit; x < XEnd; x=XInit<XEnd?x+1:x-1){
       for(int y = YInit; y < YEnd; y=YInit<YEnd?y+1:y-1){
         for(int z = ZInit; z < ZEnd; z=ZInit<ZEnd?z+1:z-1){
            //do stuff
           }
        }
     }
```

Note: You may even want to abstract the calculation of XInit, XEnd etc. parameters in a separate method.

Comment: Could you give complete answer? Which values should `XInit, XEnd, YInit, YEnd, ZInit, ZEnd` have for case1, case2 and case3?

Comment: I have not specified that because it depends on the logic used by the application. The relation between user input and iteration order is not clear from the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your "stuff" is likely accessing the values of x, y, and z, so the way you're hard-coding is probably the easiest to follow.  Your method names could clearly indicate the ordering.  For the three examples you gave, it would look similar to:

```
public void somethingXYZ(Build build, Stuff stuff) {...}
public void somethingZYX(Build build, Stuff stuff) {...}
public void somethingXnYZ(Build build, Stuff stuff) {...}
```

When you're coding and want to select one of those methods, your IDE will even help you by listing the available options for that class.  I think the way you're organizing it would already work well.